# Do I need to test actual API calls made by Front End Client App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I am relatively new to C# and JavaScript and I am making an ASP.NET/React/Redux application. I wrote a simple HTTP post request using superagent:

```
import request from "superagent";

export const authenticationService = {
    login
};

function login(email, password) {
    return request.post("http://localhost:55903/api/login/contractor")
                  .type("form")
                  .send({ EmailAddress: email})
                  .send({ Password: password })
                  .then((res) => {
                      return res;
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                      return err;
                  });
};
```

My main Question is do I need to UNIT TEST the actual login function itself? So far examples I have seen just mock HTTP responses to test the React/Redux side of things, but I haven't seen examples where HTTP request functions such as the one above are tested.

Comment: Are you trying to run integration or unit tests?  You use mocks for unit tests.

Comment: I am trying to run unit test

Comment: You don't have to because we assume `superagent` works properly. It would be an integration test instead of a unit test if we were to test the actual call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, on the Front end side it is best to mock data since you aren't testing the HTTP request, you are testing that your React application is displaying the proper thing.

However the HTTP request should be tested, but on the back end side. So your testing of the login request should happen with your C# code not with your React/Redux code.